# How do I make players on Roblox spawn as different objects?

Tags: lua, roblox

For example: In my game I want player to spawn as a ball? How will I accomplish this? I can't find it anywhere on the web, though I have searched and searched. I haven't got any code because I haven't the simplest idea of how to do this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Almost every popular language has `SpawnABall` function and Lua is no exception. I'm sure it's in the documentation somewhere. If not, you'll need to write one yourself. It's likely to involve [Object Creation via Script](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Instantiation_of_a_part).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will check the site out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first; You'd probably have better luck over at https://scriptinghelpers.org/questions it's like Stack Overflow but for only Roblox related questions.

now, if you want the player to spawn as anything other than the default player, you have to do one of two things, prevent the character from loading, or remove it when it does, once you've accomplished that, you should bind the camera to the desired object, and bind movement to keys.

an easier, but much less elegant solution would be to find and modify a standard character morph to simply make it appear that you're a ball.